# Pandas: Compare two dataframes and replace with specific value if not available in column?

Tags: pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['AUD','CAD', 'SMI','Joy', 'SHA', 'CHY', 'AUD', 'KRL'], 
       'sal': [200,300,600,500,300,200,100,350]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['SMI','Joy', 'SHA', 'CHY'], 
       'sal': [600,500,300,200]})
```

I want to compare above two dataframes by 'name' column and if values of df2 'name' is not available, then df1 'name' replace to 'Others'. My expected output as below

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Others','Others' ,'SMI','Joy', 'SHA', 'CHY','Others','Others'], 
       'sal': [200,300,600,500,300,200,100,350]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `where` and `isin`:

```
df1['name'] = df1['name'].where(df1['name'].isin(df2['name']), 'Others')
```

Output (`df1`):

```
     name  sal
0  Others  200
1  Others  300
2     SMI  600
3     Joy  500
4     SHA  300
5     CHY  200
6  Others  100
7  Others  350
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using just `np.where`:

```
In [1164]: df1.name = np.where(df1['name'].isin(df2['name']), df1.name, 'Others')
```

**OR:**

You can use `df.merge` with `numpy.where`:

```
In [1152]: import numpy as np

In [1153]: res = df2.merge(df1, on='name', how='right')
In [1155]: res.name = np.where(res.sal_x.isna(), 'Others', res.name)

In [1159]: res = res.drop('sal_x', 1).rename(columns={'sal_y':'sal'})

In [1160]: res
Out[1160]: 
     name  sal
0  Others  200
1  Others  100
2  Others  300
3     SMI  600
4     Joy  500
5     SHA  300
6     CHY  200
7  Others  350
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pandas `where` method. Essentially, this performs a substitution based on a boolean mapper performed on an iterator:

```
df1['new_name'] = df1['name'].where(
    df1['name'].isin(df2['name'],
    df1['name'],
    'Others')
```

To break this down, you can create a boolean column and map it yourself:

```
map = df1['name'].isin(df2['name'])
df1['name'].where(map, 'Others')
```